# ¿Como inicializar propiedad de clase con método estático de la misma?

Tags: php

Buenas.

Tengo un atributo de clase que quiero inicializar con otro atributo estático de la misma clase, el problema es que ninguna de las formas que he intentado asignándole el valor funciona. Este es el código que tengo:

```
<?php

class ClaseEjemplo {

    public static $name = "santiago";

    //protected $asd = self::$name; //No funciona
    //protected $asd = static::$name; //No funciona
    //protected $asd = ClaseEjemplo::$name; //No funciona
    //protected $asd = ClaseEjemplo::$name; //No funciona
    //protected $asd = ClaseEjemplo::name; //No funciona

    protected $asd;

    // esto si funciona
    ///*
    function __construct(){
        $this->asd = self::$name;
    } //*/
}

$clase = new ClaseEjemplo;
var_dump($clase);
```

Se que con el constructor se puede inicializar, pero me pregunto si se puede inicializar solo asignándolo.

Para probar el código uso este [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas conseguir? ¿O es solo curiosidad esto que planteas?

Comment: Es que la clase del ejemplo extiende desde otra que tiene la propiedad protected como un array (y no puedo modificar esa clase por que es parte de un marco de trabajo), y necesito que se inicialice con ciertos datos que se mantienen para todas los objetos de la clase hija (la que yo he creado), pero finalmente la curiosidad de saber como se puede (o si no se puede) me ha llevado a preguntar esto :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso no lo puedes hacer con una variable static. Como su valor se asigna en tiempo de ejecución, estarías haciendo competir ambas variables. El orden en que las declaras no implica que cuando asignes el valor de `$asd` ya tengas previamente asignado `$name`.

**Peeero**, lo que quieres **sí se puede hacer** con una [constante de clase](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
<?php
class ClaseEjemplo {

    const NAME = "santiago";

    protected $asd= self::NAME;


    function __construct(){

    } 
}

$clase = new ClaseEjemplo();
var_dump($clase);
```

Revísalo en el [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c116717f6781cd5bbb2f00541e120a01b7011aab).

Comment: Pero entonces es una constante, no una propiedad de la clase :/

Comment: y la pregunta dice "con un método estático" pero lo está intentando con una propiedad estática. Por eso tuve que asumir que lo que realmente quiere es manipular $asd sin tocar el constructor, para no tener que usar `parent::__construct()` o anda a saber por qué

Comment: hmm comprendo lo de la asignación. pensé que era como Java :P

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta [tu comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52417/como-inicializar-propiedad-de-clase-con-m%C3%A9todo-est%C3%A1tico-de-la-misma?noredirect=1#comment92948_52417), te diré que los constructores están, precisamente, para inicializar clases; si tienes una clase que hereda de otra (como es el caso) y necesitas establecer un valor en el momento de la instanciación, lo más sensato es hacerlo en el constructor.